# Get current page number after adding a big chunk of data

Tags: .net, pdf, itext

I am using the following code to add big chunk of data to a PDF file, which likely will fit more than one page. I need to add a bookmark linking to the next page. In order to do that I need to get the current page number. However the `document.PageCount` is not available. How could I get number of pages in the current PDF file?

```
doc.Add(new Paragraph(new Chunk(StringWithBigChunkData)));
```

Comment: Shouldn't you rather look at `document.PageNumber`?

Comment: Find the solution. document.PageNumber doesn't work. PDFWriter.PageNUmber is the right property. Thanks.